# Changes to _settings not recognized

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I've set up the foundation framework for compilation with Compass. Everything works fine except that changes to the _settings file are not compiled to my app.css.

That's my (nearly) original app.scss file:

```
@import "settings";
@import "custom/settings";
@import "foundation";
```

If I make changes to the _settings.scss file, Compass shows me the following information:

```
>>> Compass is polling for changes. Press Ctrl-C to Stop.
>>> Change detected at 10:23:56 to: _settings.scss
identical stylesheets/app.css
```

Which means it looks like the **@import command is recognized** but it **doesn't lead to any changes** in the compiled app.css. And in fact the CSS isn't changed. The "custom/settings" file is imported and compiled to app.css correctly.

Has anybody an idea or hint for me what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be unsupported except if you're using Ruby or similar.

http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import